# How to load beans based on custom properties

Tags: spring, properties, configuration, spring-boot, configuration-files

I have custom implementation of `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`, which I'm using to load additional property sources and placing them into different position (one on the end, and one before systemProperties). So properties can be overridden on different level.

Based on some properties, I need to load set of beans. For that I'm implementing `ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar`.

Unfortunately that `ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar` is executed before `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`.
I also tried to use `@ConditionalOnProperty`, with the same result. And with `PropertySourceFactory` which is executed on the early beginning, but at that point I can't position those additional property sources.

Is there a way to add additional `PropertySource` in custom order before `ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar`, or on the early beginning of Spring lifecycle?

Here I have [sandbox app](https://github.com/d-sauer/ExploringSpringBootConf) to play with the concept. 
In reality I have this as in house library for Spring and Spring Boot applications, to enable additional functionalities with properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement [`EnvironmentPostProcessor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.0.RC1/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-the-environment-or-application-context) and move all the logic for the property sources there. You current project is broken in the sense that you have no guarantee that `@PropertySource` is going to be processed early (actually, it won't).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll try that approach. Unfortunately I'm building that concept as in house library for Spring and Spring Boot application. Is there something similar for Spring based applications (legacy without Spring Boot)?

Comment: If you implement a regular Spring application, you are in hands of loading the context. So just write some code that customize the environment before the context is refreshed. [This issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14386) is probably related.